# Keeping untracked files in git repo

Tags: git, version-control

I have a question about some, probably very niche operation that may or may not be possible. I think the answer may be somewhere near, but perhaps due to my failure to formulate the question well, I am not finding it. So here it goes:

Imagine a simple git repo with a few commits that contain a bunch of files and pretty much nothing else.
What I want to do is to add a binary file in such a way that when it is modified, git updates the file but does not keep any of its history. So each time the file is changed, Git updates the actual data, but otherwise assumes it is unchanged.

The goal is to keep always-up-to-date version of a relatively big binary files that are required for the project but don't track them.
The operation should not involve rebase and must be supported by popular git hosts (such as github)
Edit: also the goal is to be able to clone git repo, run compile script and get the results immediately. So "keep these files in dropbox" is not a solution.

Is this even possible? Where should I look, Git LFS maybe? Seem to be not quite what I want. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it’s impossible. This is because git will track the changes if the file added in git, so when you made any changes, git will find it.

There are some solutions you can refer:

- Ignore this file in `.gitignore` .
- Convert the binary file as ordinary file if possible (docx to txt, xlsx to csv etc), and then version control it.
- Commit changes normally, and clean the old version of the binary file for a period of time by `git filter-branch`.

Comment: I see. I am aware of `git filter-branch` and this is pretty much what I am using, but I was hoping for a solution that will be transparent for other git repo users and will not affect them in any way after the operation is performed.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same requirement. Please let me describe it simplely:

1. Users still can download the `update ignored` files, such as a base disk image `rootfs.img`, by `git clone`.
2. But when users build their own images by using the original image `rootfs.img` as a base, and then update it of cause, `git` should ignore the changes of this `rootfs.img`

This feature is useful when want to maintain or use a sdk package of one embedded system.